# Computation of size in titlespacing

Tags: titlesec, calculations, lengths, dimensions, units

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength{\textsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex} % WORK
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{\dimexpr(3.5ex-1.\textsize)\relax plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex} % FAIL

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

and the error:
[image]

How to make the failing expression work in order to reduce the space by a textsize?

Comment: Please always make the example reproduce the error and show the full error that you get. You say `% FAIL` but you do not say what error you get, and I get no error running the above example?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Working example and error provided now.

Comment: @Vincent I think I've found the real reason and modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\titlespacing` command uses some tricks for extracting the `plus` and `minus` dimensions and doing some computations; the `\relax` token disturbs the processing, because `\relax` is used as terminator of an argument in one of the internal macros.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength{\textsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\textsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {\glueexpr (3.5ex-\textsize) + 0pt plus 1ex minus .2ex}
  {2.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use

```
\the\dimexpr 3.5ex-\textsize\relax  plus 1ex minus .2ex
```

which will remove the unwanted `\relax` when evaluating `\dimexpr`.

Comment: I was just going to say that:-)

Comment: It's titlesec looking for a `*` as far as I can see.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's not really the `*`, but `\relax`: see the definition of `\ttl@assign@d`.